# C error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Tags: c, string

I want to make easy Caesar encrypting code, but i getting this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    printf("\t\t\t\t\tCaesar Encrypt\n");
    printf("Input shift value: ");
    int shift;
    scanf("%d",&shift);

    const char EngAlp[26] = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
        'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    char inp[20]="";
    printf("\nEnter a word: ");
    scanf("%s",inp);
    FILE *fp = fopen("EncMessage.txt","w");
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(inp);i++)
    {
        int pnt=0;
        for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(inp[i],EngAlp[j])==0) fprintf(fp,"%c",EngAlp[j+shift]);
            else pnt++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to make const char the alphabet array, but getting same error.

Error line is: `if(strcmp(inp[i],EngAlp[j])==0) fprintf(fp,"%c",EngAlp[j+shift]);`

Comment: When you say `if(strcmp(inp[i],EngAlp[j])==0)`, it looks like you're comparing characters, not strings.  You use `strcmp` to compare strings.  For characters you can use plain `==`.

Comment: If you do a `#include <ctype.h>`, you can use the `isalpha()` function to check for alphabetic characters much more easily.  (But before your program is finished you're going to have to worry about (1) wraparound from `z` to `a` and (2) upper-case letters.)

Comment: To compare individual characters, use the `==` operator; To compare strings use `strcmp()` function. That should get you in the right direction.

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you, i didn't know i can compare chars with plain ==. Solved. But i don't know how to close question, can you explain?

Comment: Yes, he teached to me. @machine_1

Comment: @frogwine You don't need to "close" the question.  If there were any official answers, you could "accept" one of them by clicking on the check mark.  But since there aren't any official answers (yet), just comments, there's nothing you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried plain "==" operator for character by the answers, it's solved.